# Revolution surface with zero mean curvature and never-zero Gauss curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to find the (2-dimensional) revolution surface whose Gaussian curvature is never zero and mean curvature is always zero.

I know that the matrix of the Weingarten map for a revolution surface is

$$
         \left(\begin{array}{cc}
      \frac{-f''(u)}{g'(u)} & 0\\
     0 & \frac{g'(u)}{f(u)}
     \end{array}\right)
$$
where $\rho=f(u)$ and $z=g(u)$, $u$ being the arc length of the curve to be revolved.

We know that our principal curvatures are such that

$$
      \begin{cases}   k_1+k_2=0
\\    k_1k_2\ne0
      \end{cases} 
$$
Thus $k_1= \frac{-f''(u)}{g'(u)} = -k_2 = -\frac{g'(u)}{f(u)}$, and the Gaussian curvature is $K=k_1k_2<0$. We can therefore write it $K=-\frac{1}{a^2},\ a$ positive. Also, $K=-\frac{\rho''}{\rho}$. Hence $\rho''=\frac{\rho}{a^2}$, and we can write 
$$
       \rho(u)=Ae^\frac{u}{a} + Be^{-\frac{u}{a}}
$$
Now:
$$
             \frac{\rho''(u)}{z'(u)}  = \frac{z'(u)}{\rho(u)}
  \\   \iff  \frac{\rho(u)}{a^2z'(u)} = \frac{z'(u)}{\rho(u)}
  \\   \iff        (z'(u))^2          = \frac{\rho(u)^2}{a^2}
  \\   \iff          z'(u)            = \pm\frac{\rho(u)}{a}  =
  \\     =    \pm \frac{Ae^\frac{u}{a} + Be^{-\frac{u}{a}}}{a}
$$
Hence
$$
        z(u) = \pm (Ae^\frac{u}{a} + Be^{-\frac{u}{a}}) = \pm \rho(u)
$$
and this seems to indicate that we are in the presence of a cone. But I must be missing something quite elementary, because the cone has zero Gauss curvature. Any hints?

---

Thanks to Anthony Carapetis, I now know what the problem was: I assumed that $K$ was constant, and of course that does not need to be the case.

I now get the following system of differential equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
             \rho(u)'+z'(u)=1
\\           -\frac{\rho''(u)}{\rho(u)} = K(u)
\\            \frac{\rho''(u)}{z'(u)}   = \frac{z'(u)}{\rho(u)}
\end{cases}
$$

Unfortunately, my experience with differential equations is quite limited. The only thing that I see that can be useful is to differentiate the first equation to get
$$
      \frac{\rho''(u)}{z'(u)} = -\frac{z''(u)}{\rho'(u)}          
$$
and we can substitute this in the system. I still do not know what do now, though.

Comment: Given your definition, I'm not actually sure that there is a unique surface that meets the definition. The Catenoid is one, but is it the only?

Answer (score 4):

You're assuming $K$ is constant, and thus you're only going to find the flat plane - it is the unique minimal surface of constant Gauss curvature.

If you allow $K$ to depend on $u$, then you should be able to solve the resulting differential equations to find the catenoid. Remember that there's really only one function worth of freedom in a surface of revolution; so in your formulation you will need to use the fact $f'(u)^2 + g'(u)^2 = 1$ in order to solve the ODE arising from $k_1 + k_2 =0$.

Comment: I found the cone, not the plane, right?

Comment: @Soap: If you found anything, it's a proof by contradiction that there is no surface of revolution with zero mean curvature and non-zero constant Gaussian curvature. Yes, the $z$ and $\rho$ you arrive at seem to parametrize a cone; but they *don't* do it by arclength, so they don't have the relationship to the principal curvatures that you claim.

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: @Soap: your arclength equation is incorrect - you forgot the squares. Once you add the squares in, you should easily be able to eliminate $z$ from the mean curvature equation, giving you an ODE for $\rho$. The substitution $h = \rho^2$ should help you solve the ODE. You don't need to treat $K$ as part of the system - just use the fact that it is non-zero to constrain the constants of integration once you have a general solution.

Comment: Oh, of course. I found that $\rho(u)=-\sqrt{u^2+Au+B}$.

Comment: In theory, I can solve for $z(u)$ now. I am clueless how this can be proved to be the catenary, though

Comment: @Soap: looks good. (other than the sign?) If you want to recover the usual parametrization of the catenoid, I guess you should solve for $\rho$ as a function of $z$, since you're really revolving the curve $\rho(z)$.

Comment: The sign is wrong. 
Yes. It is not going to be easy, though, because $z(u)$ will not be pretty. 
Thanks.

Comment: Wolfram alpha gave me $\rho(u) = \sqrt{2 c_2 u + c_2^2 - c_1 + u^2}$ and $z(u) = k_1 \pm \sqrt{c_1} \tan^{-1}\frac{c_2 + u}{\sqrt{c_1 - (c_2 + u)^2}}$. I used Sage to isolate $u$ and got a very complicated expression. I do not know how to verify that it is a catenary.

Answer (score 1):

The **catenoid** is a surface of revolution in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the following parametrization:
\begin{align}
x(u, v) &= r \cos(u) \cosh(v/r)\\
y(u, v) &= r \sin(u) \cosh(v/r)\\
z(u, v) &= v.
\end{align}
Its Gaussian curvature given by
$$-{sech^4({v\over r})\over r^2},$$
where $r$ is the radius.

This surface is one of the simplest minimal surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$, meaning that the mean curvature $H$ is always zero.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to prove (using the differential equations above) that it is the catenoid, though, not simply state the result.